# How to remove the default error message for a *required input field

Tags: oracle-adf

When user does not enter a value in a required field, there is a default error message that is getting displayed on the field. This error message is not pointing to the required field. And, the error message box is moving when page is scrolled on Chrome browser. The requirement is to either point the error message to the correct field and it should move along with the field when scrolled or to remove only the error message that appears like a tip next to the required fields, while highlighting the field in red and showing the error at the bottom. Please let me know for any more information. Thank you!

[image: Error Message]

Comment: Tell us your exact JDev version, please! Do you see this behavior in Chrome only?

Comment: Hi Timo, the JDev version is 11.1.1.9.0, and yes this behavior is observed only in Chrome browser (version: 77.0.3865.120). I've tested on firefox and IE browsers, this issue does not appear on these browsers. Thank you!